# Print in Local Printer but Connected to Server PHP

Tags: php, printing

I have a direct printing in PHP using printer functions but we have two printers and only one printer can be added in printer_open(printer name). How can the other pc with different printer can print in their respective local printer?

Answer (score -1):

Use [google cloud print](https://www.google.com/cloudprint/) as an alternative, it's easy and fast to configure

or you can symple use the javascript in your php code to make the client browser open the print option, use this in your php code

```
<?php 

echo '<script language="Javascript1.2">


  window.print();


</script>';

?>
```